# How to get a value into xml output?

Tags: xml, xslt

first time asking here but have been searching around without finding an answer to my problem so thought id give it a try.

The output i need has to look exactly like the example below but i need to to get the value of the currency as well:

> ```
> <DBField name='Currency' value='USD'/>
> ```

I tried this with no success:

> ```
> <DBField name='Currency' value='<xsl:value-of select="Currency"/>'/>
> ```

Anyone with an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

You could make use of the **xsl:attribute** command.

```
<DBField name='Currency'>
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
       <xsl:value-of select="Currency"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</DBField>
```

Alternatively, you could use "Attribute Value Templates"

```
<DBField name='Currency' value='{Currency}'/>
```

The curly braces indicate it is an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally.

Generally, using Attribute Value Templates are preferred, as they are much neater to write. You would use **xsl:attribute** where you want an attribute shown only in certain conditions (e.g, you can put it inside and **xsl:if**), or if you wanted a dynamic attribute named, based on the XML input.